# Why such a modest passmark score increase in single vs dual CPU?

Tags: cpu, performance, dual-core

I understand a bit about having more cores vs having faster cores and how this plays with different workloads.

A single E5-2690v3 CPU has a passmark of 18k, while the dual CPU variant only increases that to 25k.   Why is the increase in Passmark score between single and dual CPU so modest?

Relatedly, if these CPUs are being used in a VM server running KVM, would pinning specific cores to VMs provide a total possible throughput equivalent to a score of 36k ?

Comment: I see there is a downvote  this is opinion based - If anyone else thinks this way, can they elucidate why?  From my POV CPUBenchmark is running a performance test, and thus must be testing specific things.  I seek to understand some of the limitations in this metric, or alternatively I seek to understand why [Haswswll] CPUs don't scale well in parallel, and the extent this problem can be generalized and mitigatgated

Comment: Every result depend on how it use the hardware. You need low enough communication (and need async communication) between the two CPU to get linear boost. The communication also include software on one CPU access RAM undercontrol of another CPU.

Comment: You're asking two questions right now. Could you focus on a single question perhaps? Give us a more narrow target.